# probability of getting repeat samples in multiset

Tags: probability

If I have multi-set S, where elements of S takes value from domain D = {d1, d2, ..., dm} and each di appears vi times in S. If I uniformly sample 10 elements from S, what is the

*P (there is no duplicated item in this sample)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is with replacement.  If you want without replacement leave me a comment.

Let $V = \sum_i v_i$.  The total number of ways to draw 10 things with replacement from this set is $V^{10}$.

Now let $X$ be the set of all 10-element subsets of the set $\{1, \dots, m \}$.  For any particular 10-element subset $x \in X$ define $f(x) = \prod_{i \in x} v_i$.  For every subset there are $10!$ orders for us to draw those items in, and for any given order there are $f(x)$ ways of drawing *those specific items* from their respective groupings.  So the total number of ways of getting no duplicates is:

$$
10! \cdot \sum_{x \in X} f(x).
$$

So in the end, the probability we wanted is:

$$
\frac{10! \cdot \sum_{x \in X} f(x)}{V^{10}}.
$$

**edit: Clarification**

I want to help you understand what $X$ and $x$ are above.  For simplicity let's say assume $m=4$ and instead of drawing 10 elements we're drawing 3.  $X$ is the set of all 3-element subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,4 \}$.  For example one of these subsets would be $\{1,3,4\}$.  If $x = \{1,3,4\}$ and I want to compute $f(x) = v_1\cdot v_3 \cdot v_4$.  This equals the number of ways of choosing one element of type 1, one of type 3, and one of type 4.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that it's without replacement from a multi-set, and multiplicity of each element di is vi

Comment: If you reread, I take into account the $v_i$.  Now that I think of it, only one small thing has to change in order to take into change the answer to without replacement.  What is it?

Comment: I don't understand how you define f, how does it depend on x? besides, X is the set of all 10-element subsets, so subsets with duplicated items are also in X, right? So how can you sum over all x in X?

Comment: @lbzl Added a lot of clarification and fixed the definition of $f$.  Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @lbzl does the answer make sense, do you understand why each component is there?  Is it clear how to fix it for the without replacement case?

Comment: I believe I understand every thing. The numerator is the number of ways to get distinct items in each possible sample x. If it's sample without replace, should I simply change the denominator to 10!*C(V, 10)?

Comment: Yep.  Notation for that number is $(V)_{10}$.  This is called the falling factorial.  It equals $V \cdot (V-1) \cdot \dots \cdot (V-9)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack-exchange. I think I just accepted it.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to make sure you were satisfied with the answer.